# WordPress bulk data send in custom API endpoint

Tags: woocommerce, endpoint, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I create a custom end point in wordpress, I use woocommerce authentication CK and CS. and I test to get sent array which is about 6000 data. How can I get full count of data?
the result of json response is just 2000 data

```
   add_action('rest_api_init', array($this, 'import_csv'));
   public function import_csv(){
        register_rest_route('wc', 'csv_importer', [
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => array($this, 'csv_importer_callback')
        ]);
    }
    
    public function csv_importer_callback(WP_REST_Request $request){
        if (is_user_logged_in() && (int)wp_get_current_user()->ID === 2) {

            return new WP_REST_Response(count($request['update']), 200);
        }
        return new WP_Error('unauthorized', __('You Are Unauthorized'), [ 'status' => 401 ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the REST API response is capped with the **Blog pages show at most** option in WP-admin > Settings > Reading

But you can overcome this for your CPT using the following code:

The hook is **rest_{$this->post_type}_query**

Replace CPT with your custom post-type like product

```
add_action( 'rest_CPT_query', 'CPT_override_per_page' );

function CPT_override_per_page( $params ) {
    if ( isset( $params ) AND isset( $params[ 'posts_per_page' ] ) ) {
        $params[ 'posts_per_page' ] = PHP_INT_MAX; //Defaults to system value, you can also put your own number. It is not suggested to put 999999 type of value.
    }

    return $params;
}
```

I hope this helps in some way.